# Python str is not callable error with date

Tags: python, type-conversion

I'm thinking this is impossible to do, but anyway I would like to have the user input a date for the nsepy get_history function, It has to be in  yyy,mm,dd format

```
df = get_history(symbol=inSymbol, start= date(dateA),end=date(2018,7,23))
```

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. I need a way to input a date or datetime from the keyboard. Trying to convert it does not work.
Trying this currently:

```
inSymbol = input("Enter Symbol: ") 
date = input("Enter start date: ")
dateA = datetime.strptime(date, '%y,%m,%d')
df = get_history(symbol=inSymbol, start= date(dateA),end=date(2018,7,23))
```

Comment: `date` is a string. `dateA` appears to be what you want. What's `date(dateA)`?

Comment: As MoxieBall points out, `date(dateA)` makes no sense. Instead, just do `start=dateA`. Similarly, `date(2018,7,23)` doesn't work because you reassigned the name `date`. I suggest that you pick a different variable name such as `date_str` so that it doesn't conflict with the standard `date` function.

Answer (score 1):

The primary problem is that Python has a function named `date()`. But you reassign `date` to be a string from user input:

```
date = input("Enter start date: ")
```

I suggest that you change the variable name to something else so that it does not conflict with the `date()` function.

Even with that, you need to change `start=date(dateA)` to `start=dateA` because `dateA` is already a date object.

Comment: Thanks, tried that it gives ValueError: time data '2018,1,1' does not match format '%y,%m,%d' Not sure if this is even possible to do? Should be simple...

Comment: @RobD Please update your question to show the newest version of your code and the entire error message.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got it needed output_file(ticker + ".html")